# Weather program (I've made a start and encountered an error)

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python program to the following specification:

> -store for each month of the year, the average monthly temperature, for a chosen location
>
> -select a combination of months, and calculate and display the total average temperature for these months rounded to the nearest integer

Here is what I wrote:

```
months = ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

#user input
location = input("Where in Scotland are you? ")

for i in range(12):
    
        temps  = int(input("Enter the average temperature in celsius for []",months[i])) 

monthsSelected = input("Please select a combination of at least two months: ") 

#output
print("Monthly average temperatures: January: [Jan] February: [Feb] March: [Mar] April: [Apr] May: [May] June: [Jun] July: [Jul] August: [Aug] September: [Sep] October: [Oct] November [Nov] December [Dec]")

print("Average Temp for these months:", sum(temps) / 12)
```

When I run the program I encounter this:

```
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

I don't understand what this means. Could anyone suggest a fix and/or any improvements I can make?

(You may remember me from a post submitted around an hour ago that basically asked you to write my program for me. Well I took the advice of a user and read through some tutorials on python lists and arrays and provide the start of my program.)

Comment: `"Enter the average temperature in celsius for []",months[i]` is **not** how *any* of Python's string formatting methods work; you are just passing two separate arguments to `input`, hence the (very clear!) error. Please consider reading a tutorial.

Comment: It's always refreshing to see someone improving the quality of their questions. Nice work. For your question, you're passing two arguments to int in this line: `int(input("Enter the average temperature in celsius for []",months[i]))` You probably want to try formatting the string: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: Its good that you want to learn and improve. May I suggest less personal commentary for example 'Thanks for helping out a noob", "Good evening...". Just focus on the technical aspects, personal commetary is frowned on here.

Comment: I'm sorry jon but you must understand I am very new to this. Thanks for the suggestion but could you clarify at all?

Comment: Will keep it in mind, paisanco, thanks.

Comment: Second hit on Google for *"tutorial Python string formatting"*: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting. As a rule, **don't** require users to trawl through your previous questions for context (especially as that one won't last long) - each question should stand alone. *"you must understand I am very new to this"* - there are plenty of tutorial resources out there already, we aren't here to write another introductory Python book.

Comment: Thanks Jon, any tips for the second part of the specification?

Comment: @ZakDavis One problem with your question is that someone who doesn't remember your question one hour ago arrives to your program without you having said what it is you are trying to do. I would have removed the first paragraph at the same time I removed the thanks (neither belong in a SO question), but it's the only clue at to what it is your are trying to do (which is bad, since it doesn't really say it).

Comment: @PascalCuoq There was not anything important in my previous question that isn't here (program specification carried over). Thanks for the edit anyway.

Comment: @ZakDavis People read from top to bottom. If they encounter a program before you have said what you are trying to do, what do you expect they will do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
1\Arrays are defined by **[ ]**, so

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
```

2\The format string is not correct

```
temps  = int(input("Enter the average temperature in celsius for [%s]" % months[i]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, any tips for this: 

-select a combination of months, and calculate and display the total average temperature for these months rounded to the nearest integer.

Doesn't have to be the actual code, even a suggestion of what to use would be really useful